# How can I align layers side-by-side and crop them automatically in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I align layers side-by-side and crop them automatically in Photoshop CS5?

Here's an example:

[image]

---

Here is another example:

[image]

I found the solution with this sprite generators, but all them have the same problem: a really small size limitation:

http://www.shoutmeloud.com/9-great-free-online-css-sprite-generator.html

Comment: What do you mean by "Crop them automatically?" Can you explain a bit more about what you really want to do? For example, show us the source image and what result you need.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/align-layers/

(Note that this distributes the layers based on the pixels of your images, not the size of the layers themselves)